# Cannot figure out what is happening with python os.rename

Tags: python

```
file_number = len(os.listdir(directory_path_display_var.get()))
    directory_path = directory_path_display_var.get()
    count = 0

    for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory_path, file),
                  os.path.join(directory_path, f"{name_replacement_var.get()} {count}"))
        count = count + 1
        
       if file_number == 10:
            os.rename(os.path.join(directory_path, file),
                      os.path.join(directory_path, f"{name_replacement_var.get()} {dummy_data} {count}"))
```

I have no clues what is happening. It just keeps saying that the file specified is not found. If I remove the code snippet of the if statement (if file_number == 10)..., then it works fine.

This is what I am trying to achieve, there are 10 files in a folder and I would like to iterate and rename them all but the last file, which I want to rename differently. This is the error message, hope somebody could help.

**os.rename(os.path.join(directory_path, file),
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:/Users//Desktop/Tour France\yyyyy' -> 'C:/Users/Desktop/Tour France\uuuuu dummy data'**

Comment: When your `file_number == 10` block is executed, you're trying to rename a file you *just* renamed 3 lines up.  It no longer exists with the original name.  On each iteration, you should pick the name you want and then make a single `os.rename` call to use that new name.

Comment: If there are 10 files in the folder, which one is "the last file"?  `os.listdir()` does not produce any guaranteed ordering of files...

Comment: thanks, I also figured that out myself after carefully reviewing the code. Thanks for the sharp eyes.

BTW, jasonharper, if I would like the ordering of the file before renaming, shall I use the order function first to order the file before renaming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop renames (or at least tries to rename) each file twice, so it can't find the file you just renamed.
Also, your `if file_number == 10:` condition is always true, as you have defined this variable in your first line of code, and given that you said you have 10 files in your folder. So you have to check `if count == 10:`.

Keeping with your code structure and everything (using a counter, and expecting the last file to have number `10`, try it the following way:

```
file_number = len(os.listdir(directory_path_display_var.get()))
directory_path = directory_path_display_var.get()

count = 1
for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if count == 10:
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory_path, file),
                  os.path.join(directory_path, f"{name_replacement_var.get()} {dummy_data} {count}"))
    else:
        os.rename(os.path.join(directory_path, file),
              os.path.join(directory_path, f"{name_replacement_var.get()} {count}"))
    count = count + 1
```

Please note that `os.listdir()` returns the order that the native filesystem uses. You can also use `for file in sorted(os.listdir(directory_path)):`.